# how to get the individual id of an item in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, ejs

i have a delete api, it takes in the id of the item we want to delete, each item has its unique id, how do i get the id of the item the wants to delete and pass it to my api

here is the api

```
    app.post("/delete_product", function (req, res) {
            var data = {
                id: req.session.user_id,
                token: req.session.token,
                product_id: 4
    // you need to pass in the id of the product in data.product_id
            };
           functions.callAPIPost(
                "https:/theurl/delete_product",
                data,
                function (error, result) {
                    var response = result;
                    if (response.status === 400) {
                        console.log('ggg',response)
                        res.render('products', {
                            result: result.data
                        })
                    } else {
                        res.redirect('logout')
                    }
                }

            );
        });
```

this is my ejs

```
<form method='post'  action='/delete_product'>
       <button><iclass="os-icon os-icon-trash" style='font-size: 16px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 10px; color: #8095A0;'></i><span>Delete</span></button>
</form>
```

i have an array of objects, which display as items in the browser after i loop thru them, they all have their individual id, how do i get the id once a user clicks on the item delete button that call the api to delete it.

```
 [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "work dress",
            "description": "take to work dress",
            "price": "2000",
            "created_at": "2020-02-26T20:30:08.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "movie dress",
            "description": "take to movie dress",
            "price": "2000",
            "created_at": "2020-02-26T20:30:08.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "home dress",
            "description": "stay at home dress",
            "price": "2000",
            "created_at": "2020-02-26T20:30:08.000Z"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it through the POST URL and access the value in NodeJS via `req.params`.

In EJS -

```
<form method='post'action='/delete_product/<%= product._id %>?_method=DELETE'>
```

In NodeJS -

```
app.delete("/delete_product/:id", function (req, res) {

    var id_to_delete = req.params.id;

    //rest of the code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [hidden input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden)

```
<input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='1' />
```

Then in your api you can pick it up in the POST data object

Comment: Can you edit your post to point here instead please? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden We don't want to send people to [w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com).